# Multi Language Shopify site

Tags: shopify

Any idea how to run multi language Shopify site? JavaScript hacks are not the solution, cause it breaks SEO. I can't imagine how to do it by templates and pages.

Answer (score 4):

I would say: Don't duplicate your store. We did it once and it was a nightmare. (you need to have duplicate products, duplicate collections, duplicate pages, duplicate settings...) It all depends on your company size and how many people you can allocate to each store. We used the translator app and it's working pretty good though checkout is not translatable.

**UPDATE:** (february 2015)

There's 2 new localization apps in Shopify:

a.- [Langify](https://apps.shopify.com/langify) (good solution but it really dirts a lot your liquid code)

b.- [Localize.js](http://localizejs.com/) (great solution and incredible clean and fast dashboard, which uses its own strings database so you don't use Shopify metafields)

Sticking back to your question, answers are:

1. Use david option (open one store for each language).
2. Use any of the i18 available Shopify apps.
3. No way by using liquid as you'll need to create a session to set the language, and this can only be done with JavaScript.

You can see an example of a Shopify store with multiple languages (spanish+catalan+english) here: [Pienso para perros - Dr. Pet](http://www.drpet.es)

Comment: Localize.js recently came out with a localization app integration for shopify https://apps.shopify.com/localize

Comment: Localize.js is great! 2 major great points: a.- it doesn't mess at all with your shopify theme (other apps make liquid code almost unreadable). B.- it doesn't mess with your Shopify metafields. It loads pretty fast and the interface is just great!

Answer (score 1):

Call up Shopify. Ask for a deal on a needed second shop. You can re-use your templates of course. Now just edit your inventory to have your second language translations. Import.

You can provide language switcher links in your shop. Of course, if inventory counting is important, allocate half to each shop.

To run your show, bookmark both admins, and now you're in business.